# My php code is always sending a false response even when its not supposed to

Tags: php

As the title says, I'm a newbie that just started learning html php and css 3 days ago, so far so good yet while testing a semi login system (obv an ineffective one)
i came across the fact that my code doesn't work and always sends a false answer to the code which results in the "else" code to be activated. wondering why.
the $name and $password get their value from another properly configured file.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if ($name == ['Tal'] && $password == ['14']) {
echo "Hello, " . $name;
} else {
echo 'Either the name or the password (or both) is incorrect.';
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (Your title says nothing about the problem, also consider googling and learning about the problem before posting)

Comment: @Keloo fixed the title i guess? i dont want to do some research cause im trying to write it off my mind, from an idea to it being made. and slowly get experience.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by comparing form data against arrays?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález understood ;) thanks.

Comment: @Tal.liud The title is better. But hey, programming is not like math, you can not learn it on your own by logic and deduction. You need to study documentations (like PHP documentation on arrays and strings and if condition), PHP was invented and so you need to learn what people created if you want to use it IMHO, no offense.

Comment: @Keloo Yea i understood that the moment alvarogonzalez has spoken, i understood i lack the knowledge and thus i shouldn't try and make anything meaningful (as in other than echo 'Hello World';) until i have that knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if ($name == 'Tal' && $password == '14') {
    echo "Hello, " . $name;
} else {
    echo 'Either the name or the password (or both) is incorrect.';
}
```

You shouldn't use `['Tal']` because that's an array. If you write `var_dump(['Tal']);` you will see something like this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Tal" }`. And if you write `var_dump('Tal');` you will see `string(3) "Tal"` which should be equals to $name.

---

**First things first:**

1. *[A string is series of characters.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)*
2. *[Array is a group of related data values (called elements) that are grouped together.](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/array.htm)*

---

**The problem:**

Lets say `$name` is `Tal` and `$password` is `14`. Both of those values are strings. With your code `$name == ['Tal']` you are basically comparing single string to an array of strings which is never true.

For the simplicity, imagine comparing a single character `t` to an array of characters `tal` (in real world, array of characters is a sentence). **`t` is not equal to `tal` and never will be.**

It's same with your code, single string is not same as an array of strings. That's why I converted an array `['Tal']` to a single string `'Tal'` **because the `$name` you received from the form is not an array**, it's a single string `'Tal'` and it will produce `true` in your if statement.

---

**Var_dump**

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) - Dumps information about a variable. I used it to show you that `['Tal'])` and `'Tal'` are not the same. One is an array, one is a string.

```
Code:
var_dump(['Tal']);

Produces:
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Tal"
}
```

- Type: **array**
- Number of elements: **1**
- First element index: **0**
- First element type: **string**
- First element length: **3**
- First element value: **Tal**

---

```
Code:
var_dump('Tal');

Produces:
string(3) "Tal"
```

- Type: **string**
- Length: **3**
- Value: **Tal**

I hope you know the difference now.

Comment: Would you care to explain more please? for example what does var_dump(['Tal']); do and what does its output mean